# List items by category

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I have 3 tables:

category `doesnt matter`

item2cat: `itemID|catID`

item: `id|name|desc`

I want to list the items that are in the given category, but I don't know how to do it in a simple way. (With PHP and MySQL)

I need this table-structure because I want multiple categories to one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the item2cat table on your item table:

```
SELECT
  item.id
, item.name
, item.desc
FROM item
INNER JOIN item2cat ON item.id = item2cat.itemID
WHERE item2cat.catID = [category_id]
```

or for example

```
SELECT
  item.id
, item.name
, item.desc
, category.id
, category.name
FROM item
INNER JOIN item2cat ON item.id = item2cat.itemID
INNER JOIN category ON item2cat.catID = category.id
WHERE category.id IN ( [category_id], [category_id], [category_id])
```

**UPDATE**
If you changed your table IDs like this:

```
item (itemId, name, desc)
item2cat (itemId, categoryId)
category (categoryId, name, etc)
```

you could rewrite the first query like:

```
SELECT
  item.itemId
, item.name
, item.desc
FROM item
INNER JOIN item2cat USING( itemId )
WHERE item2cat.categoryId = [category_id]
```

Another advantage is that the `id` column of every table is now unambiguous.

Comment: Why using a LEFT OUTER JOIN if you only want to list items in a given cateogry? using an INNER JOIN should be much more efficient and would avoid unnecessary full-scans

Answer (score 0):

This one should be efficient and get all relevant items in a given category:

```
SELECT item.* 
   FROM item2cat
      JOIN item 
   ON item.id = item2cat.itemID
      and item2cat.catID = $categoryID
```