# Querying results by categories and displaying everything as list

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've a table, basically its something like

```
------------------
id | name  | type
------------------
1  | name1 | type1
2  | name2 | type2
3  | name3 | type3 
------------------
```

I would like to query it and display it into something like

```
type1
 - name1
 - and so on...
type2
 - name2
 - and so on...    
type3
 - name 3
 - and so on...
```

I am also looking to display it as a JSON file which is something like

```
   [
    {
        "type1": {
            "name": "name1"
        },
        "type2": {
            "name": "name2"
        },
        "type3": {
            "name": "name3"
        }
    }
]
```

So, may I know the best way to do it? 
Using loops to query the type, then selecting the categories and displaying it by type?

Edit : 
After searching high and low in the internet. I've found this : http://www.tommylacroix.com/2008/09/10/php-design-pattern-building-a-tree/

Hence formulated this code for my needs. Not sure if it's efficient :

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$list = array();
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if(!$list[$row['type']])
    {
        $list[$row['type']] = array();
    }
    array_push($list[$location['type']],&$row['name']) ;
}
?>
```

Comment: In the JSON, what if there are multiple names with the same type?  How will the type be serialised?  It's not valid for an object to have multiple members with the same name `name`...

Comment: @steveOhh Check my answer below i hope it will work for you.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This.... also see the *result output* below

```
SELECT id,CONCAT_WS(',',type,name) as result FROM table GROUP BY id

<?php
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT id,CONCAT_WS(',',type,name) as result FROM table GROUP BY id");
$data = array();
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $ex_res = explode(",",$row['result']);
    $data[$ex_res[0]]['name'] = $ex_res[1];  
    $i++;
}

$a = json_encode($data);
print_r($a);
?>
```

**Result Output**

```
{"type1":{"name":"name1"},"type2":{"name":"name2"},"type3":{"name":"name3"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But do you think
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905917/listing-items-by-category-in-php
is better? just wanna get to know the available and best options. :D